# slack incoming webhook - send message to another channel

Tags: webhooks, slack-api, slack

I am trying to post message to any channel in a slack team.

My webhook has been properly created and installed into my test team. As part of the install process, I selected "**Post to #channel1**"

When I review permissions, I see my app has been granted Other/Post to specific channels in Slack (#channel1).

From there, I am able to post into #channel1 with a basic JSON request:

```
{
    "text":"Hello, World!"
}
```

Now I want to validate I can use same webhook to post to any other channel of the same team. So I created a channel #channel2 and I try the following request:

```
{
    "channel":"#channel2",
    "text":"Hello, World!"
}
```

The request is accepted (HTTP Status 200) but it still publishes on **#channel1**.

What am I doing wrong ? Is that a syntax or permission issue ? I guess it is more a permission issue but I have not found how to grant my app access to additional channels (or all channels).

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I created an incoming Webhook, and I found this documentation (see image)

I followed the instructions given in that, and I found that it worked. I can send a message to a different channel than the one the Incoming Webhook was set for

[image: Overriding Slack Channel in a webhook]

Answer (score 0):

The app needs the `chat:write:bot` permission to post messages to other channels.

The permission can be added in [Manage Apps](https://api.slack.com/apps) → your app → OAuth & Permissions:

[image: The default permission, and the permission necessary to post to other channels / users.]

Reading Slack's [own documentation](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks), this was not obvious to me. (although it is mentioned under ["Using the Web API" in the Intro to Messaging.](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages#using_the_web_api))