# Settings of Incoming WebHooks configuration are ignored

Tags: slack, dynatrace

We have created an Incoming WebHooks configuration so that Dynatrace can post alerts to our development channel. This worked great for a while, but later on, we decided to use a separate "operations" channel for notifications. So I changed the "Post to Channel" setting of our Incoming WebHooks configuration and expected that the notifications would appear in the new channel.

However Slack seems to ignore my new "Post to Channel" setting. It keeps posting to the previously configured channel. What am I doing wrong?

I also noticed that the other attributes in the configuration seem to be ignored. E.g. we did not customize the name and icon, but the alerts were still posted with the name "Dynatrace" and a Dynatrace icon. But I am sure that I'm looking at the right configuration because I navigated to the configuration from one of the alert posts. This is really confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was driving me nuts, so I decided to post it here - including the solution that I had found in the meantime:

If the Incoming WebHooks app has [certain permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225066/slack-incoming-webhook-send-message-to-another-channel), the caller of the web hook URL may [override the configured channel, name, and icon](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/incoming-webhooks#runtime_customizations). This is why messages posted via a specific Incoming WebHooks configuration may be using completely different settings!

Dynatrace is using these override features for alert messages, so alerts will always go to the channel configured on Dynatrace side.

Comment: The solution is correct, but your further conclusions are not. Incoming webhooks have not been deprecated, just renamed to Internal integrations. I guess you are confusing them with outgoing webhooks. Also: While you find the override function confusing, others may find this very useful.

Comment: I removed that part from your answer

Comment: Also: If please this as solution, so this question can be closed. Thank you!

Comment: Do you suggest that I accept this answer? I will, but I can only do this [48h after posting the question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). BTW, it's great that you are helping me using Slack - but I think that I mostly don't need help using SO ;-)